# how to send params from other view modal form to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application in which user can add a question, so user will fill the modal form, I have two model Client_prefernces and questionnaire 
questionnaires table has set of the questions,  add question modal form is in the client_preferences view template,

Questionnaire controller create method

```
def create
    @question = Questionnaire.new(clientPreference_params)
    @question.save
    redirect_to(saveJson_client_preferences_path)
end

private
  def clientPreference_params
    params.permit(:addedLabel, :addedQuestion)
  end
```

params are

```
 Parameters: {"data_curated_id"=>"", "addedLabel"=>"style", "addedQuestion"=>"whats your fashion type"}
```

how to capture that params in questionnaire controller create an action to create an entry in questionnaires table and then redirect to saveJson_client_preferences_path(which is a get action in client_preference controller to display questions)

I am getting this error

> undefined method `addedLabel=' for #

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `addedLabel` is a column/field of `Questionnaire` model/table?

Comment: its done , i solved it, I renamed my addedLabel as label and addedQuestion as text same as questionnaire table column

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you strong parameter code to

```
def clientPreference_params
   params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:addedLabel, :addedQuestion)
end
```

Hope it works.

Comment: there is no column addedLabel and addedQuestion in questionnaires table so i had to rename it to column names, label and text

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
params.require(:questionnaire).permit(yourModelname_1: params[:addedLabel], youModelname_2: params[:addedQuestion])
```

As it allows you to interact with parameters attributes available from a request you implemented.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.